# A question related to the definition of quadratic form.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $\Bbb F$ ($\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$) and let $q: V\to\Bbb F$ be a mapping. Then is it true that the following two conditions are independent, that is one does not imply the other?

1. $q(ax)=a^2q(x)$ for all $a$ in $\Bbb F$ and for all $x$ in $V$.
2. The mapping defined by

   $$\varphi_q(x , y)=q(x + y) - q(x) - q(y)$$

   is a bilinear form on $V$.

As both the above conditions should be satisfied for the mapping $q: V\to\Bbb F$ to be called as a quadratic form on $V$. Hence my question is can there be a mapping $q: V\to\Bbb F$ such that condition (1) holds but (2) does not and vice-versa. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Do you mean $q(ax)=a^2\color{red}{q(x)}$ in the first condition?

Answer (score 3):

The first condition only constrains the function values along each ray individually. For instance, if $V=\mathbb R^2$ over $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$, you could assign arbitrary values to $q$ on the unit circle and then extend $q$ to $V$ such that the first condition is fulfilled. Most such functions will not fulfil the second condition, which connects function values on different rays.

On the other hand, any linear function $q$ fulfils the second condition, since in this case $\phi_q$ is identically zero, so the second condition also doesn’t imply the first.

Comment: That's wrong. It should be $q(x,x)=q(x+x)-q(x)-q(x)=q(2x)-2q(x)$ in the second displayed equation.

Comment: @anankElpis: Oops, you're right. Let me see if can salvage it.

Comment: @anankElpis: OK, I "salvaged" it by reversing the result :-) Thanks for catching the error.

Comment: @joriki: Thank you very much. Answer is absolutely clear. But is it possible for a mapping q to induce a nonzero bilinear form via condition (2) yet condition (1) is not satisfied.

Comment: @MrityunjayPandey: Sure – add a quadratic function and a linear function. Then the quadratic function induces a non-zero bilinear form and fulfils condition $(1)$; the linear function doesn't affect the bilinear form but causes the sum to violate condition $(1)$.

Comment: @joriki: Perfect answer. Thank you once again for your response.